# Windows: Display background image without shell

Tags: windows-7, shell

I want to have a restricted kiosk station without explorer.exe running, to keep the users from doing anything but the application I choose for them.

I set `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon` > `Shell` (REG_SZ) to, say, `cmd.exe`. When doing that, I get a black screen with the command line window after login.

Is there any way to have a background image? Black is *not always* beautiful...

Answer (score 0):

What you want to change is the appearance of the logon desktop, Windows 7 doesn't have a exposed way of changing that, but there is a lot of articles in the web explaining the registry hacks for doing it, just search "logon desktop wallpaper", for example:

[How to Set a Custom Logon Screen Background on Windows 7, 8, or 10](https://www.howtogeek.com/112110/how-to-set-a-custom-logon-screen-background-on-windows-7/)

Comment: As a remark, beware of the google autocomplete in this particular case, because it would offer "*logan* desktop wallpaper", which is not what you want unless you are also a Wolverine fan, that baffled me for a few seconds until I noticed what was going on :-)

Comment: Are you sure this is what I need? I do not show any logon screen as the "kiosk" user is being logged in automatically.

Comment: Well, you are changing the shell under the `Winlogon` key, I'm not 100% sure in your case because I haven't replaced the shell (maybe you need Explorer as the shell to load the background), but the logon desktop is what is shown before an user open session.

Comment: I have no problem with the background at that stage. It gets black *after* opening the session. :-(

Comment: Ah, I understand now. In that case the problem is probably caused by using a shell different than Explorer, since cmd is not going to paint a background. One question, Is using cmd a requirement? Because you can disable *a lot* of Explorer and desktop options using Local Group Policies (unless you are using a Home edition of Windows). As a example, I used it in the past to remove tabs from the desktop properties.

Comment: Yes, it is. When I start explorer.exe in the cmd, it paints the background. Using `cmd` is no requirement, it was an example. :-) The only requirement is to forbid everything (starting programs, doing shortcuts, ...) but the software I want the user to use.

Comment: In that case, either you use Explorer and forbid unwanted actions with policies (maybe you have to use them anyway, since you can start programs from cmd), or as workaround create a startup script that launch explorer from cmd, wait a couple of seconds until it starts and paints the background and them kill it (when you kill explorer from Task Manager the background remains, it could work in your situation too).

Answer (score -1):

I have the same exact issue. I tried what we applied on Windows 7 in the past but this time on Windows 10 Enterprise, no luck.

On Windows 7, we had to inject a background value in the wallpaper registry key and run the following command to make the background appear:
RUNDLL32.EXE USER32.DLL,UpdatePerUserSystemParameters 1, True

Regarding Alberto Martinez's input on the possibility to let explorer.exe go for a couple of seconds before killing it wouldn't work. Just try it... as soon as you kill explorer.exe, it also removes the background image you set. So far, the only thing I've been able to do is changing the background color.

Comment: Could the downvoter please explain his/her reasons?

Comment: I hope this downvoter will retract, I'm trying to help here. BTW I'm still trying to find a solution to this on Windows 10... I see you flagged Windows 7, is your issue related to Windows 7 or Windows 10? Thanks.

Comment: Windows 7. — Actually, I sometimes kill `explorer.exe`on purpose in my daily windows life, the background never disappeared! But I do not want to start it at all if I can manage that. — What do you mean by "inject a background value in the wallpaper registry key"?